# Using raster image fill and simple fill together in QGIS symbol selector

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, fill

In ArcMap I have USGS BMP files for geological lithology patterns to fill a polygon. When I choose Picture fill symbol and add one of this BMP files then as a second fill layer I choose simple fill symbol from symbol selector together. It changes my BMP file's background color which color as I pick from simple fill symbol layer.

Select BMP file for the Picture fill symbol:

[image: select bmp file for the Picture fill symbol]

[image: symbol selector combines both Picture fill symbol layer and simple fill layer]

Symbol selector combines both Picture fill symbol layer and simple fill layer with simple fill color as raster background.

But in QGIS (3.2.0 Bonn) I cannot do this use raster image fill and simple fill together to change raster background color. I also try this with PNG file types as a raster image fill. However I couldn't succeed it with SVG files, because whenever I convert image to SVG, symbol selector displays just blank as a SVG fill.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The tests I'm trying out the background of the pattern fill needs to be transparent and saved as a PNG. This is typically done using GIMP, Paint.net or other image software you may be using. Once I've done that, I'm getting the effect I believe you are looking for.